# dc.js, unable to render lines on a composite chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Hopefully someone can help me out here.

Having an issue with being able to render lines on a composite chart. I'm not getting any error messages and I'm able to output the values I want to chart to the console but for some reason dc fails to render any lines.

I have a feeling it's possibly an issue with how my groups are set up. Note I'm using dc v2 here (I'm unable to use a newer version unfortunately). However, I've included two line charts I've been able to render successfully in the example below and in the fiddle, both of which use the same groups as the lines I want to render in the composite chart

Below is a simplified version of my code pertaining to my issue. I already have a few charts and number displays which I haven't included here for brevity's sake.

Here is a sample of the data I am working with:

```
var ggData = [
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1990",
    "Emissions": 69593
  },
   {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1991",
    "Emissions": 68925
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1992",
    "Emissions": 69569
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1993",
    "Emissions": 69196
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1994",
    "Emissions": 66808
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1995",
    "Emissions": 64783
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1996",
    "Emissions": 66260
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1997",
    "Emissions": 65967
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1998",
    "Emissions": 64867
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1999",
    "Emissions": 65179
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2000",
    "Emissions": 64345
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2001",
    "Emissions": 63143
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2002",
    "Emissions": 62912
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2003",
    "Emissions": 60191
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2004",
    "Emissions": 58956
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2005",
    "Emissions": 56987
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2006",
    "Emissions": 54508
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2007",
    "Emissions": 52975
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2008",
    "Emissions": 49592
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2009",
    "Emissions": 46777
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2010",
    "Emissions": 41442
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2011",
    "Emissions": 41443
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2012",
    "Emissions": 39430
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2013",
    "Emissions": 37416
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2014",
    "Emissions": 36589
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2015",
    "Emissions": 35781
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2016",
    "Emissions": 35349
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1990",
    "Emissions": 3148
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1991",
    "Emissions": 3559
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1992",
    "Emissions": 4502
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1993",
    "Emissions": 5763
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1994",
    "Emissions": 7551
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1995",
    "Emissions": 8839
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1996",
    "Emissions": 10166
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1997",
    "Emissions": 11134
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1998",
    "Emissions": 11490
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1999",
    "Emissions": 12564
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2000",
    "Emissions": 13115
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2001",
    "Emissions": 14155
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2002",
    "Emissions": 15870
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2003",
    "Emissions": 17287
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2004",
    "Emissions": 18969
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2005",
    "Emissions": 20871
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2006",
    "Emissions": 22829
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2007",
    "Emissions": 24638
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2008",
    "Emissions": 25697
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2009",
    "Emissions": 26185
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2010",
    "Emissions": 27065
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2011",
    "Emissions": 28506
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2012",
    "Emissions": 30195
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2013",
    "Emissions": 31043
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2014",
    "Emissions": 32126
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2015",
    "Emissions": 33455
  },
  {
    "Source": "Cars - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2016",
    "Emissions": 35355
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1990",
    "Emissions": 7321
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1991",
    "Emissions": 7093
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1992",
    "Emissions": 6637
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1993",
    "Emissions": 6244
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1994",
    "Emissions": 5764
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1995",
    "Emissions": 5117
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1996",
    "Emissions": 4848
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1997",
    "Emissions": 4509
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1998",
    "Emissions": 4226
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "1999",
    "Emissions": 3582
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2000",
    "Emissions": 3105
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2001",
    "Emissions": 2648
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2002",
    "Emissions": 2270
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2003",
    "Emissions": 1950
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2004",
    "Emissions": 1732
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2005",
    "Emissions": 1498
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2006",
    "Emissions": 1489
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2007",
    "Emissions": 1377
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2008",
    "Emissions": 1240
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2009",
    "Emissions": 1086
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2010",
    "Emissions": 978
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2011",
    "Emissions": 902
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2012",
    "Emissions": 823
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2013",
    "Emissions": 768
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2014",
    "Emissions": 728
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2015",
    "Emissions": 684
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Petrol", 
    "Year": "2016",
    "Emissions": 650
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1990",
    "Emissions": 4380
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1991",
    "Emissions": 5002
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1992",
    "Emissions": 5590
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1993",
    "Emissions": 6187
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1994",
    "Emissions": 7193
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1995",
    "Emissions": 7854
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1996",
    "Emissions": 8757
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1997",
    "Emissions": 9671
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1998",
    "Emissions": 10211
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "1999",
    "Emissions": 10789
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2000",
    "Emissions": 11249
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2001",
    "Emissions": 11734
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2002",
    "Emissions": 12321
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2003",
    "Emissions": 13067
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2004",
    "Emissions": 13757
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2005",
    "Emissions": 14429
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2006",
    "Emissions": 14858
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2007",
    "Emissions": 15574
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2008",
    "Emissions": 14821
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2009",
    "Emissions": 14722
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2010",
    "Emissions": 15170
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2011",
    "Emissions": 15349
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2012",
    "Emissions": 15590
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2013",
    "Emissions": 15857
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2014",
    "Emissions": 16626
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2015",
    "Emissions": 17523
  },
  {
    "Source": "LGV - Diesel", 
    "Year": "2016",
    "Emissions": 18567
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "1990",
    "Emissions": 5339
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "1991",
    "Emissions": 5467
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "1992",
    "Emissions": 5393
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "1993",
    "Emissions": 5378
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "1994",
    "Emissions": 5440
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "1995",
    "Emissions": 5508
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "1996",
    "Emissions": 5569
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "1997",
    "Emissions": 5566
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "1998",
    "Emissions": 5432
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "1999",
    "Emissions": 5241
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2000",
    "Emissions": 4912
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2001",
    "Emissions": 4801
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2002",
    "Emissions": 4774
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2003",
    "Emissions": 4883
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2004",
    "Emissions": 4681
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2005",
    "Emissions": 4673
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2006",
    "Emissions": 4729
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2007",
    "Emissions": 4871
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2008",
    "Emissions": 4246
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2009",
    "Emissions": 4237
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2010",
    "Emissions": 4331
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2011",
    "Emissions": 3995
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2012",
    "Emissions": 3819
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2013",
    "Emissions": 3872
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2014",
    "Emissions": 3858
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2015",
    "Emissions": 3733
  },
  {
    "Source": "Buses and Coaches", 
    "Year": "2016",
    "Emissions": 3492
  }
];
```

And here is the code I have so far. The totalEmissionsOverTime, totalEmissionsCarPetrol and totalEmissionsCarDiesel functions currently render fine. I can't seem to figure out however why I am not able to render lines on the composite chart.

```
var ndx = crossfilter(ggData); //load the data into a crossfilter

//Dimensions
var yearDim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck("Year"));

//Groups
var totalEmissionsPerYearGroup = yearDim.group().reduceSum(dc.pluck("Emissions")),

    totalEmissionsCarPetrolGroup = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
        if (d.Source === "Cars - Petrol") {
            return d.Emissions;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }),

    emissionsCarPetrolGroup1990 = yearDim.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) {
        if (d.Source === "Cars - Petrol" && d.Year === "1990") {
            return d.Emissions;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }),

    totalEmissionsCarDieselGroup = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
        if (d.Source === "Cars - Diesel") {
            return d.Emissions;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });

//Function Calls
totalEmissionsOverTime(ndx);
totalEmissionsCarPetrol(ndx);
totalEmissionsCarDiesel(ndx);
compositeChart(ndx);

dc.renderAll();

    //Define Functions
function totalEmissionsOverTime(ndx) {
    dc.lineChart("#total-emissions-over-time")
        .width(700)
        .height(500)
        .margins({top:10, right:50, bottom: 100, left:60})
        .dimension(yearDim)
        .group(totalEmissionsPerYearGroup)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal);
};

function totalEmissionsCarPetrol(ndx) {
    dc.lineChart("#total-emissions-car-petrol")
        .width(700)
        .height(500)
        .margins({top:10, right:50, bottom: 100, left:60})
        .dimension(yearDim)
        .group(totalEmissionsCarPetrolGroup)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal);
};

function totalEmissionsCarDiesel(ndx) {
    dc.lineChart("#total-emissions-car-diesel")
        .width(700)
        .height(500)
        .margins({top:10, right:50, bottom: 100, left:60})
        .dimension(yearDim)
        .group(totalEmissionsCarDieselGroup)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal);
};

function compositeChart(ndx) {
    var compositeChart = dc.compositeChart("#composite-chart");
    compositeChart
        .width(1000)
        .height(500)
        .margins({top:10, right:50, bottom: 100, left:60})
        .dimension(yearDim)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
        .legend(dc.legend().x(80).y(20).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
        .brushOn(false)
        .compose([
            dc.lineChart(compositeChart)
                .dimension(yearDim)
                .colors("green")
                .group(totalEmissionsCarPetrolGroup, "Cars - Petrol")
                .valueAccessor(function(d) {
                    return d.value;
                })
                .dashStyle([2,2]),
            dc.lineChart(compositeChart)
                .dimension(yearDim)
                .colors("red")
                .group(totalEmissionsCarDieselGroup, "Cars - Diesel")
                .valueAccessor(function(d) {
                    return d.value;
                })
            ]);
};
```

There is a working fiddle available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dhamma1991/pt5j6amd/11/).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the composite chart works currently, it needs to be able to read enough of the data to prepare the scales/axes for the child charts.

This means it may need a group (only for ordinal X scale I think, in order to get the keys) and it needs `xUnits` to know how many ticks to show.

If you add `.group()` and `.xUnits()` to the composite chart, it draws:

```
    compositeChart
        .group(totalEmissionsCarPetrolGroup)
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
```

[image: composite chart]

[Fork of your fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/gmxq7j6f/6/)